# java implict long cast behaviour

Tags: java, casting

Today i found one of my programs to be buggy because the implicit cast was not work, better saying it was not working as I expect to be.

i had something like this

```
long normal = 1000*24*3600*1000;
System.out.println("normal :"+normal);
```

> normal :500.654.080

asking excel the right output of the computation should be 86.400.000.000;

I went to [java manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) and the max value for the long data type should be 2^63-1, that is: 9.223.372.036.854.780.000

then I tried to force the cast to long, and it seems to work:

```
    long normal = 1000*24*3600*1000;
    long explicit = 1000*24*3600*1000l; // 1000l <- letter L used at the end for long
    long cast = 1000*(long)(24*3600*1000);

    System.out.println("normal :"+normal);
    System.out.println("explicit :"+explicit );
    System.out.println("cast :"+cast);
```

> normal :500.654.080
>
> explicit :86.400.000.000
>
> cast :86.400.000.000

What I think is happening, is that java does the computation as integer an at a point the [integer overflow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) happens.

Shouldn't Java implicit cast those integers to long?

Comment: "Shouldn't Java implicitly cast [...]" well, it doesn't and it's too late now ;)

Comment: Nope. In evaluating the expression Java sees int types and does int arithmetic resulting in the overflow as you suspect. However, when it assigns the final value to  the variable it converts it to the long but by then its too late.

Comment: A warning would be nice (and more useful than many of the existing warnings).

Comment: It's behaving exactly to spec.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, when calculating with `integers`, the result will always be an `integer`, no matter of the type of the variable you use to assign the result.

Assigning one (or all) of the numeric literals as a Long is the way to go, as you have found out yourself already:

```
long implicit = 1000L*24*3600*1000;
```

EDIT: as noted in the comments, operands in Java are evaluated from left to right, so at least the first operand on the left should be assigned as Long

Comment: It's actually worse than that: Expressions (of equal precedence) are evaluated left-to-right in Java.  Therefore, you have just been lucky that the overflow only occurred in the last multiplication.  `1000 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 1L` would overflow as well.  I recommend you make all operands `long` literals to make your intent clear.  An expression with the last operand `long` and the preceding ones `int`s would certainly catch my attention.

Comment: @5gon12eder or just use literal `long` on the first element.

Comment: Both commenters are correct, the answer should be amended so that the first argument is marked as long; this way it is safer.

Comment: Also, completely off topic, I would advise against using lowercase l there, it looks too much like the number one. Use uppercase instead.

Comment: @5gon12eder The statement 'expressions (of equal precedence) are evaluated left-to-right in Java' is incorrect. It is *operands* that are evaluated left-to-right, *regardless* of precedence. And it is not necessary to 'make all operands `long` literals'.

Comment: @EJP Well, what I wanted to say is that for example `1L + 1000 * 24 * 3600 * 1000` would still overflow.  I'm not too familiar with the JLS' terminology but what if not precendence is the right explanation here?  It is not *necessary* to make all operands `long` (or whatever type conversion you wish) as far as the compiler is concerned.  But as I've said, I *recommend* to do so nevertheless to make the programmer's intent clear to the human reader.

Answer (score 2):

When you use numbers without the `L` postfix Java will interpret this as `integers`, the default number in the language. The calculations will always be done in `int` as well, so you'll experience the overflow.

If you cast or use an explicit `long` value all the values in the calculation are 'promoted'/widened to long values. This is described here in the language specification:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2

The expression is evaluated before the assignment to the variable (which has type `long`), so Java isn't aware of the overflow and doesn't promote anything in your first example.

Answer (score 2):

> java implict long cast behaviour

There is ***no*** 'implicit long cast behaviour' in Java. You have to enforce it yourself, by using a long literal or a `(long)` typecast. Your code doesn't do that, so the value is calculated in `int` precision. If you want `long` precision, do one of the following:

```
long normal = 1000L*24*3600*1000;
long normal = 1000*24L*3600*1000;
long normal = 1000*24*3600L*1000;
long normal = 1000*24*3600*1000L;
long normal = (long)1000*24*3600*1000;
long normal = 1000*(long)24*3600*1000;
long normal = 1000*24*(long)3600*1000;
long normal = 1000*24*3600*(long)1000;
```